# sqlsrv_query not working and no error

Tags: php, sql

Currently I am trying to execute this code, it doesn't return me any error. It get's in the If that returns the $Query but doesn't actualy insert the values in the database. If i grab the $Query form the echo and paste it on Management Studio it inserts correctly. Can you help me on what am i doing wrong?

```
<?php 
$tmp = $_POST["field2"];
$qual = $_POST['field7'];

$servername = "gghj";
$ligar = array("database"=>"ztt","uid"=>"abwt","pwd"=>"22231");

$ligando = sqlsrv_connect($servername, $ligar);


if($ligando) {

$Query = "INSERT INTO PHCINQUERITOSUPORTE (tempoform,qualform) VALUES($tmp,$qual)";

$do = sqlsrv_query($ligando,$query);
 if($do === false)
        {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
    else{
        echo $Query;
        echo "<script> ;
   $(window).on('load',function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
}

</script>";
    }
    }else{
    echo "morreu"; 
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),TRUE));
    }    
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem. You have used `$query` when trying to run the query, but `$Query` every other time. Remember PHP is case sensitive when it comes to variables. So if you declare a variable and the variable name contains a capital letter(s), you must ensure when calling the variable you have the capital letter(s) in the right place otherwise it thinks you are trying to call a different variable.

In your case just change `$do = sqlsrv_query($ligando,$query);` to `$do = sqlsrv_query($ligando,$Query);` and it will work.